# Why does it say error: ';' expected when I compile it?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
    double gallons = (beginningMeterValue - endinggMeterValue)/10;
    double residential == (15.00 + 0.0005(gallons));
    double commercial == (1000.00 + 0.00002(gallons));
```

It say that every line is missing a ';'

Comment: `residental` and `commercial` aren't assigned, you're using comparaison operators.

Comment: It doesn't say anything when you run it. You can't run it. It gives these errors when you *compile* it.

Answer (score 3):

`double residential == (15.00 + 0.0005(gallons));` you're assigning value to a variable, you only need one equal sign. Also I don't think `0.0005(gallons)` work, if you're trying to multiply this use `(15.00 + (0.0005 * gallons))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might missed some code to add , you have to declare the value of variables
`beginningMeterValue`  and `endinggMeterValue`

```
double residential == (15.00 + 0.0005(gallons));
double commercial == (1000.00 + 0.00002(gallons));
```

This code doesnt work you need to assign the value but here you might need = sign  and 0.00002(gallons) doesnt work
 the below is the sample code

```
    double beginningMeterValue =10.00;
    double endinggMeterValue = 20.00;
    double gallons = (beginningMeterValue - endinggMeterValue)/10;
    double residential = (15.00 + 0.0005*gallons);
    double commercial = (1000.00 + 0.00002*gallons);
```